# Hyperlink from one DataTable to another in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a Shiny app that consists of two pages:

- Page 1 displays a DataTable with summary information (`ensembles`).
- Page 2 displays detailed pricing info (`items`) for a specific ensemble, which is selectable.

When the user clicks on a row on page 1, I want them to be taken to page 2, with the corresponding ensemble selected.

[image]

The below code creates the Shiny app and the two pages, but requires the user to switch pages and enter the ensemble number manually.

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)

## Create item pricing data
set.seed(1234)
init_items = function() {
  item.id=1:1000
  ensemble.id=rep(1:100,each=10)
  cost=round(runif(1000,10,100), 2)
  profit=round(cost*runif(1000,0.01,0.15), 2)
  price=cost+profit

  data.frame(item.id, ensemble.id, cost, price, profit)
}
items = init_items()

## Create ensemble pricing data
init_ensembles = function(items) {
  items %>% group_by(ensemble.id) %>% summarize_each(funs(sum), cost, price, profit)
}
ensembles = init_ensembles(items)

## Attach dependencies
## https://github.com/timelyportfolio/functionplotR/issues/1#issuecomment-224369431
getdeps <- function() {
  htmltools::attachDependencies(
    htmltools::tagList(),
    c(
      htmlwidgets:::getDependency("datatables","DT")
    )
  )
}

# Define UI for application
ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage("Linked Table Test",
             tabPanel("Page 1", uiOutput("page1")),
             tabPanel("Page 2", uiOutput("page2"), getdeps())
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$page1 <- renderUI({
    inclRmd("./page1.Rmd")
  })

  output$page2 <- renderUI({
    inclRmd("./page2.Rmd")
  })
})


# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**page1.Rmd**

````
# Ensembles

Click on an ensemble to display detailed pricing information.
```{r}
tags$div(
  DT::renderDataTable(ensembles, rownames = FALSE)
)
```
````

**page2.Rmd**

````
# Items

```{r}
inputPanel(
  numericInput("ensemble.id", label = "Ensemble ID:", 0, min(ensembles$ensemble.id), max(ensembles$ensemble.id))
)

tags$div(
  renderText(paste0("Detailed pricing information for ensemble #",input$ensemble.id,":"))
)
tags$div(
  DT::renderDataTable(items %>% filter(ensemble.id==input$ensemble.id) %>% select(-ensemble.id), rownames = FALSE)
)
```
````

Comment: I've never heard of `inclRmd`, but that is not relevant. This can be done using javascript. Will post an answer once I figure it out.

Comment: @Carl Got it.  I got rid of inclRmd in my later experiments, since it was mostly R code (and very little markdown) anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you the tools to do what you want:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("One",
             DT::dataTableOutput("test1")
    ),
    tabPanel("two",
             numericInput("length","Length",0,0,10)
    )))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- reactive({
    cbind(seq_len(nrow(mtcars)),mtcars)
  })
  output$test1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df()
  },rownames=FALSE,options=list(dom="t"),
  callback=JS(
    'table.on("click.dt", "tr", function() {

    tabs = $(".tabbable .nav.nav-tabs li a");
    var data=table.row(this).data();

    document.getElementById("length").value=data[0];
    Shiny.onInputChange("length",data[0]);
    $(tabs[1]).click();
    table.row(this).deselect();})'
  ))

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When you click a row in the datatable, it switches tabs, and changes the value of the numeric input to the value of the first column in the row you selected.

edit: you will probably have to put your datatables explicitly in the shiny app and not include them from a r markdown script, since I don't believe shiny objects in R Markdown have html Ids in a reliably readable way.

edit: I took your code and got it to work:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
## Create item pricing data
set.seed(1234)
init_items = function() {
  item.id=1:1000
  ensemble.id=rep(1:100,each=10)
  cost=round(runif(1000,10,100), 2)
  profit=round(cost*runif(1000,0.01,0.15), 2)
  price=cost+profit

  data.frame(item.id, ensemble.id, cost, price, profit)
}
items = init_items()

## Create ensemble pricing data
init_ensembles = function(items) {
  items %>% group_by(ensemble.id) %>% summarize_each(funs(sum), cost, price, profit)
}
ensembles = init_ensembles(items)

## Attach dependencies
## https://github.com/timelyportfolio/functionplotR/issues/1#issuecomment-224369431
getdeps <- function() {
  htmltools::attachDependencies(
    htmltools::tagList(),
    c(
      htmlwidgets:::getDependency("datatables","DT")
    )
  )
}

# Define UI for application
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(#id="Linked Table Test",
    tabPanel("Page 1", DT::dataTableOutput("page1")),
    tabPanel("Page 2", inputPanel(
      numericInput("ensemble.id", label = "Ensemble ID:", 0, min(ensembles$ensemble.id), max(ensembles$ensemble.id))
    ),
    textOutput("page2"), DT::dataTableOutput("table2"),getdeps())
  )
))

# Define server logic
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$page1 <- DT::renderDataTable(ensembles, rownames = FALSE,
                                      callback=JS(
                                        'table.on("click.dt", "tr", function() {

    tabs = $(".tabbable .nav.nav-tabs li a");
    var data=table.row(this).data();
    document.getElementById("ensemble.id").value=data[0];
    Shiny.onInputChange("ensemble.id",data[0]);
    $(tabs[1]).click();
    table.row(this).deselect();
    })'                     
                                      ))


  output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable(items %>% filter(ensemble.id==input$ensemble.id) %>% select(-ensemble.id), rownames = FALSE)

  output$page2 <- renderText({
    print(input$ensemble.id)
    paste0("Detailed pricing information for ensemble #",input$ensemble.id,":")
  })
})


# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In order to use the `deselect()` method, I had to add the `Select` extension to the datatable (explained here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html)