# R/shiny change tab and input on dynamically generated link clicked

Tags: r, dynamic, datatable, shiny, tabs

I am trying to add dynamically generated links to a datatable of variable length. Clicking the link should switch the focus to the details tab. At the same time, the select input should be updated to the car brand that was clicked, so that the information on the details tab is updated. I prepared a minimal example with actionLinks. However, I couldn't figure out how to make the links do what I want.

```
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(tibble)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("car", h3("Car"),choices = rownames(mtcars))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "dataset",
        tabPanel("Cars", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")),
        tabPanel("Details", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable2"))))))

server <- function(input, output) {

  shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, labels, ...) {
    inputs = NULL
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = labels[i], ...))
    }
    return(inputs)
  }

  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    cars <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column() %>% select(rowname, mpg, cyl)
    cars$rowname <- shinyInput(actionLink, nrow(cars), "link_", labels = cars$rowname)
    DT::datatable(cars, rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE)
  })

  output$mytable2 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(mtcars[input$car,]))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700633/r-shiny-datatable-link-to-another-tab.

Furthermore, I can only think of giving your tabset panel an ID first, i.e. `tabsetPanel(id="yourID", tabPanel... ` and trying to implement an observer that  does `updateTabsetPanel(session, "yourID", selected = "Details")`. I know this isn't a satisfying answer as the observer lacks a target input, but perhaps it helps you to find the right solution.

Comment: Thanks much for your input. It helped me to find a solution. I added the id to the example, since I use it in the solution I came up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using the onclick function of the button and JavaScript statements. To open the tab, simulate a click on it and to change the drop down menu use selectize.

```
 shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, labels, ...) {
    inputs = NULL
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = labels[i], 
         onclick = paste0('$("#dataset li a")[1].click();$("#car")[0].selectize.setValue("',labels[i],'")')))
    }
    return(inputs)
  }
```